# Native SIP client in Samsung Galaxy S2 Android version 4.1.2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, sip

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 which is upgraded to Android 4.1.2. I did not find the SIP settings. Where have they gone to?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `phone > menu > call settings > internet call settings > accounts`

Comment: Can't find "internet call settings" on my S2

Comment: On some roms there's not such option, but some roms have that.